# Docker Compose Bundle Install Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, bundler, gemfile

I am calling `docker-compose run web bundle install --jobs=8` from inside a container in Github CodeSpaces. The command is failing with the following error:

```
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://enterprise.contribsys.com/ due to underlying error
```

This occurs for any gem I try to fetch with the command invocation. When I run bundle install inside of the container, it works.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.4-slim

RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    docker.io \
    gnupg \
    build-essential \
    git \
    pkg-config \
    libvips \
    curl \
    node-gyp \
    libpq-dev \
    shared-mime-info \
    ffmpeg \
    tzdata \
    net-tools \
    awscli \
    jq \
    python3-full \
    python3-pip \
    python3.11-venv \
    docker-compose \
    ; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV SOPS_VERSION 3.7.3

RUN curl -LO https://github.com/getsops/sops/releases/download/v${SOPS_VERSION}/sops-v${SOPS_VERSION}.linux.amd64 && \
    mv sops-v${SOPS_VERSION}.linux.amd64 /usr/local/bin/sops && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sops

# Install node
ARG NODE_VERSION=16.15.0
ARG YARN_VERSION=1.22.19
ENV PATH=/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ && \
    /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "${NODE_VERSION}" /usr/local/node && \
    npm install -g yarn@$YARN_VERSION && \
    rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master

WORKDIR /redacted

# specify bundle location so we can use a volume to store installed gems
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_BIN=/bundle/bin
ENV GEM_HOME=/bundle
ENV PATH="${BUNDLE_BIN}:${PATH}"

# ARG SIDEKIQ_KEY
RUN bundle config gems.contribsys.com $SIDEKIQ_KEY
RUN bundle config enterprise.contribsys.com $SIDEKIQ_KEY

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.4.6 --no-document && bundle config set frozen 'true'

COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
RUN MAKE="make --jobs=$(nproc)" bundle install

# ARG NPMRC
RUN test -n "NPMRC" || (echo "Must run 'export NPMRC=\$(cat ~/.npmrc|base64)' before building image to install private yarn packages" && exit 1)
RUN sh -c 'echo NPMRC| base64 -d > ~/.npmrc'

COPY package.json  .
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY .npmrc .

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --no-progress
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    command: bundle exec rdbg --open --host 0.0.0.0 --port 12345 --nonstop --command -- puma --port 80 --bind tcp://0.0.0.0 --threads 4 --workers 1
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - "NPMRC=redacted"
    working_dir: /redacted
    volumes:
      - .:/redacted
      - bundle-cache:/bundle # so bundle installed gems can be cached
      - yarn-cache:/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6 # so yarn's global cache persists
      - webpack-data:/redacted/public/packs # persist data even if container shuts down
      - node-modules:/redacted/node_modules # share node_modules
      # let container have the following all to itself
      - /redacted/public/packs-test # might be able to deprecate this requirement?
      - /redacted/public/javascripts/i18n # maybe should never have been checked in to repo?
      - /redacted/tmp # because rails is dirty with pid files sometimes, also doing this for tmp is probably a good call anyway
    ports:
      - "80:${redacted:-80}" # web server
      - "12345:12345"
    environment:
      BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM: redacted
      BUNDLE_ENTERPRISE__CONTRIBSYS__COM: redacted
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      DATABASE_NAME: redacted
      DATABASE_USER: redacted
      LAUNCH_DARKLY_USER_ID: redacted
      redacted_HOSTS: hogwarts.redacted.local # pass through for development.rb hosts config
      PAGER: busybox less # otherwise pry gem uses some unavailable flags for the environment
      PIDFILE: /dev/null
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ: redis://redis:6379/1
      WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: webpack
      SMTP_ADDRESS: mail
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - app.redacted.test

volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
  webpack-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
  bundle-cache: # to cache bundled gems
  node-modules: # to cache node modules
  yarn-cache: # to cache yarn's global cache
  caddy_data: # For caddy's persisted data
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '~> 3.1'

source 'https://enterprise.contribsys.com/' do
  gem 'sidekiq-pro'

  # Include the enterprise version after pro
  gem 'sidekiq-ent'
end

gem 'active_hash', '~> 3.2'
gem 'activerecord-import', '~> 1.5'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 9.0' # Revisit @ Rails 6 and 7 upgrade
gem 'addressable', '~> 2.8'
gem 'algoliasearch-rails', '~> 2.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 10.4'
gem 'aws-sdk-core', '~> 3.181'
gem 'aws-sdk-elastictranscoder', '~> 1.45'
gem 'aws-sdk-rds', '~> 1.192'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1.134'
gem 'bamboo-id', '~> 0.1.3', require: 'bamboo_id'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1'
gem 'bootsnap', '~> 1.16', require: false
gem 'browser', '~> 5.3'
gem 'carrierwave', '1.3.2' 
gem 'chunky_png', '~> 1.4'
gem 'composite_primary_keys', '~> 14.0'
gem 'counter_culture', '~> 3.5'
gem 'd3_rails', '~> 4.1'
gem 'daemons', '~> 1.4'
gem 'ddtrace', '~> 1.14'
gem 'dogstatsd-ruby'
gem 'embedly', '~> 1.9'
gem 'faraday', '~> 1.10'    # @TODO: add https://rubygems.org/gems/faraday-follow_redirects; update where FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects is used
gem 'faraday-cookie_jar', '~> 0.0.7'
gem 'fog-aws', '~> 3.19'
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.53.0', require: 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
gem 'henkei', '~> 2.6' # A beast. @TODO: consider simple_text_extract
gem 'htmlentities', '~> 4.3'
gem 'html_to_plain_text', '~> 1.0'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.21.0'
gem 'i18n-js', '~> 3.9'
gem 'icalendar', '~> 2.9'
gem 'ice_cube', '~> 0.16.4'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.12'
gem 'json', '~> 2.6'
gem 'jsonapi-serializer'
gem 'jwt', '~> 2.7'
gem 'launchdarkly_api'
gem 'launchdarkly-server-sdk', '6.4.0'
gem 'logidze', '~> 0.12.0' # @TODO needs work to migrate past 1.0 - 0.12 does support Rails 6
gem 'lograge', '~> 0.13.0'
gem 'loofah', '~> 2.19'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.12'
gem 'mini_portile2', '~> 2.8.1'
gem 'money', '~> 6.16'
gem 'net-sftp', '~> 4.0'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.15'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.9' # blocked primarily by omniauth-stripe-connect which is abandoned since '19
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.8.2' # Set to '~> 1.0' if omniauth-stripe-connect ever allows us to go to omniauth 2.x
gem 'omniauth-salesforce', '~> 1.0'
gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect', '~> 2.10'
gem 'pagy', '~> 5.10'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 14.0'
gem 'paranoia', '~> 2.6'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.4.5'    # Not Semver, check changelog before updating
gem 'premailer-rails', '~> 1.12'
gem 'puma', '~> 6.3.1'
gem 'pundit', '~> 2.3'
gem 'rack', '~> 2.2'
gem 'rack-cors', '~> 2.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.5' # Not Semver, check changelog before updating
gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.5.5'
gem 'react_on_rails', '~> 11.3' # Revisit @ Rails 6 and 7 upgrade
gem 'redis', '~> 5.0'
gem 'redlock', '~> 1.3'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 2.1'
gem 'restforce', '~> 5.2'
gem 'ruby-openai', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'ruby-saml', '~> 1.15'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 2.3' # @TODO: Allowing v3 when it comes out should be safe
gem 'rustici_software_cloud_v2', '~> 2.0'
gem 'salesforce_bulk_api', '~> 1.0'
gem 'sanitize', '~> 6.0'
gem 'sassc-rails', '~> 2.1'
gem 'savon', '~> 2.14'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby', '~> 6.6'
gem 'smarter_csv', '~> 1.8'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 4.2'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.4'
gem 'string-undump', '~> 0.0.2.1'
gem 'stripe', '~> 5.48'
gem 'strong_migrations', '~> 1.6'
gem 'terser', '~> 1.1'
gem 'turnout', '~> 2.5'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 5.77'
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2023'
gem 'uuidtools', '~> 2.2'
gem 'waypoints_rails', '~> 4.0'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.4'
gem 'websocket-extensions', '~> 0.1.5'
gem 'whenever', '~> 1.0'
gem 'wisper', '~> 2.0'
gem 'wisper-activejob', '~> 1.0'
gem 'xml-simple', '~> 1.1'
gem 'Ziggeo', '~> 2.30'

# Adding coverband here because it must be after rails
gem 'coverband', '~> 5.2'

group :development do
  gem 'colorize', require: 'colorized_string'
  gem 'letter_opener', '~> 1.8'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 4.2'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'brakeman', '~> 6.0'
  gem 'bullet', '~> 7.0'
  gem 'bundle-audit'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 3.39'
  gem 'climate_control', '~> 1.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'datadog_api_client', require: false
  gem 'debug', '~> 1.8'
  gem 'execjs', '~> 2.8', '>= 2.8.1'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 6.2'
  gem 'faker', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'figaro', '~> 1.2'
  gem 'parallel_tests', '~> 4.2'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'require_reloader'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 6.0'
  gem 'rspec-teamcity', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.56', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-performance', '~> 1.19', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rails', '~> 2.20', require: false
  gem 'seed_dump', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.22.0'
  gem 'simplecov-html', '~> 0.12.3'
  gem 'simplecov-tailwindcss', '~> 2.1.1'
  gem 'simplecov-teamcity-summary', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'spring', '~> 4.1'    # Revisit @ Rails 6 and 7 upgrade. * Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'syntax_suggest', '~> 1.1.0'
  gem 'test-prof', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.9.8'
  gem 'wisper-rspec', '~> 1.1', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'pundit-matchers', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 5.3'
  gem 'super_diff', '~> 0.10.0'
  gem 'webmock', '~> 3.19'
end

# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'scenic', '~> 1.7'

gem 'tiktoken_ruby', '~> 0.0.5'
# Adding rb_sys for tiktoken_ruby. It shouldn't be needed,
# but it fails in local docker without this. Excluding the
# version to let it match the tiktoken required version.
gem 'rb_sys'
```

I am able to run bundle install in the base container, but when running bundle install with docker-compose, the gems are unreachable.

Comment: You `RUN bundle install` in the Dockerfile; it seems like mounting a volume over the image's `/bundle` directory and then running `docker-compose run ... bundle install` into the mounted volume will leave you with inconsistent content in the container, that doesn't match what the image has.  If the installation works from the Dockerfile, can you delete the entire `volumes:` block, and re-run `docker build` to get a clean image after you update the `Gemfile`?

Comment: Removing the entire volume block led to the following: `Could not locate Gemfile ERROR: 10`. If I just leave in the .:/redacted volume, which contains the content of the base container, the fetch hangs again.

Answer (score 0):

In DockerFile.

Change

```
RUN bundle config gems.contribsys.com $SIDEKIQ_KEY
RUN bundle config enterprise.contribsys.com $SIDEKIQ_KEY
```

to

```
RUN bundle config enterprise.contribsys.com abc:def 
- if use env: 'abc:def' -> $BUNDLE_ENTERPRISE__CONTRIBSYS__COM 
- I only run 'abc:def' i don't test add env. You can check)
```

or If you use ENV

In docker-compose.yml

change

```
BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM: redacted
BUNDLE_ENTERPRISE__CONTRIBSYS__COM: redacted
```

to

```
BUNDLE_ENTERPRISE__CONTRIBSYS__COM: 'abc:def'
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! So those keys are actually in place. `redacted` was just a way to not expose those secrets to the world here.

Comment: Yep, i got it. Because i am using sidekiq-pro too.